# Vim cnoremap of command expands in search

Tags: vim

in my `.vimrc` I've mapped the command `:Gedit` with the vimscript 
`cnoremap ge :Gedit`.  When I search for something like the word `target` for example, the map expands to `tar:Gedit`.  Is there a way to use a command map that doesn't expand in a search or should I just use a different mode?  I've read through the documentation and I've not seen a way to do this, however it's likely I'm missing something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want a `cnoremap`? It only works in command mode, which means you had to have already pushed `:` (in which case the `:` in your mapping is extraneous), and also has the downside you show. Why not `nnoremap`, so you can push `ge` in your normal mode? Why not `command`, so you can just replace `Gedit` with `GE`, if `Gedit` is too long? (`cabbr` will also expand in arguments, not just at the start, so it's less than ideal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use abbreviations instead of mappings.

Try:

```
:cabbr ge Gedit
```

It will wait a non-word char to expand (or simply the `<cr>` key)